Redirecting in .htaccess with RewriteCond
I'm trying to redirect this kind of URL:
kod-rabatowy/groupon/1234
kod-rabatowy/groupon/12345
To:
kod-rabatowy/groupon/
"groupon" is a variable that I want to have in new url.
So only when it ends with 4 to 5 numbers - the new one ignores the value after 2nd slash.
I tried that but I doesn't work:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^kod-rabatowy/(/.*|)/([0-9]{4,5})
RewriteRule ^kod-rabatowy/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ kod-rabatowy/$1 [R=302,L,NC]

Do you know how to fix it? I'm new to this.

This doesn't need a RewriteCond, the RewriteRule on its own is perfectly capable of matching against the URL path.

The URL path RewriteRule matches against, never starts with a leading slash, when you configure this in .htaccess. %{REQUEST_URI} however always starts with a slash, so your RewriteCond currently doesn't match. "only when it ends with 4 to 5 numbers" - you did not anchor the pattern at the end, so it would still allow for arbitrary stuff after those digits.

And with your given examples, the groupon part could be hard-coded to begin with. RewriteRule ^kod-rabatowy/groupon/[0-9]{4,5}$ kod-rabatowy/groupon/ [R=302,L,NC]

Sorry the "groupon" part was an example, only "kod-rabatowy" part stays the same.
So I want to capture the "groupon" part url in my rewrite rule.

Okay, then keep matching & capturing [^/]+ in that location, RewriteRule ^kod-rabatowy/([^/]+)/[0-9]{4,5}$ kod-rabatowy/$1/ [R=302,L,NC]

Perfect! Thank you for your help.

%{REQUEST_URI} always starts with a slash, so your RewriteCond pattern did not match here. But you don't really need to use a RewriteCond to begin with, when you only need to match on the path component of the URL - the RewriteRule can do that on its own.
RewriteRule ^kod-rabatowy/([^/]+)/[0-9]{4,5}$ kod-rabatowy/$1/ [R=302,L,NC]

should do the trick for what you want here.
